# Reference Cell in VBA Script

Tags: vba, excel

I was curious if there is a way to reference a specific cell within the following VBA script. The cell contains a date in **`yyyymmdd`** format, which would go in the commented section below.

```
Sub OpenData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

IE.navigate "http://website.com/'desired cell value'/subdirectory/file.txt"

'Check for good connection to web page loop!

Do
    If IE.readyState = 4 Then
        IE.Visible = True
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop

'Wait for window to open!
Application.wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
'MsgBox "Done"
IE.Visible = True
```

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [format](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php)?

```
'...
IE.navigate "http://website.com/" & Format (Cells(1,1).Value, “dd/MM/yyyy”) & "/subdirectory/file.txt" '...
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I've made progress but got hung up at the following error: Method'Range" of Object'_Global' Failed. Do you have any insight as to why im arriving at that error?

Comment: woops! my bad range is not needed there, check my updated answer

Comment: No worries!! Im still having struggles of my own, heres what I have, but is still giving me some issues: IE.navigate "http://www.website.com /sub/directory/ & Format (Cells(1,1).Value, “dd/MM/yyyy”) & /subdirectory/file.txt"

Comment: If what's in your comment is whats actually in your code you are missing some closing quotes. `IE.navigate "website.com /sub/directory/" & Format (Cells(1,1).Value, “dd/MM/yyyy”) & "/subdirectory/file.txt"`

Comment: Why would you need to change the format from `yyyymmdd`?  The question doesn't seem to call for that as far as I can see, and changing that format could potentially affect the end URL because of the backslashes in the date format?

Comment: This is just an example to show how format works (you'd need to change for: & Format (Cells(1,1).Value, “yyyymmdd”) only or for & Format (Cells(1,1).Value, “yyyy”)  & Format (Cells(1,1).Value, “mm”)  ... -and if this approach suit him-

Comment: This is baffling, usually I get the result after some help! I apologize for my directory changes, my internship's protocols on what we can share are strict. My reference cell is A1 in the sheet, and is labelled 6/20/2016. This is my code with the added quotes, still no luck changing the date on the URL when I run the script:

Comment: Sub OpenMyWebPage()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "http://www.website.com/directory/subdirectory/" & Format(Cells(1, 1).Value, "ddmmyyyy") &  "/3rd directory/file.txt"

'Check for good connection to web page loop!

Do
If IE.readyState = 4 Then
IE.Visible = True
Exit Do
Else
DoEvents
End If
Loop

'Wait for window to open!
Application.wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
'MsgBox "Done"
IE.Visible = True

Comment: So its critical that the date in the end product on the URL shows with no slashes and is in yyyymmdd format, I noticed I would get overflow if I formatted otherwise

Comment: If this solved your issue, don't forget to check the green mark! Have a good day